# search a paragraph in reverse order without array in perl

Tags: perl

i have a log file where the errors will be mentioned as "ERROR" in the beginning of the line and next line will have the detailed text about the error. I would like to search for "ERROR" in the reverse order so i can find the last error and print the next line or copy is the line to a variable.

In shell i can try the below command which will help me to achieve the same. Can some one give me a equivalent perl code.

```
grep -A2 ERROR sapinst.log | tail -2
```

As the log file will be huge (~5000+ lines), so I don't want to store it in an array.

Comment: See also [File::ReadBackwards](https://metacpan.org/pod/File::ReadBackwards)

Comment: If your editor can load the log file, it isn't huge yet :)

Comment: Why not just use that `grep`?

Comment: the above grep command is a shell command, i dont want to use a shell command inside my perl program.

Answer (score 4):

Your file size is rather small and perl is pretty quick, so I wouldn't worry about reverse order that much. This little program reads lines of input from the files you specify on the command line (or standard input if you specify none), skips lines until it finds `ERROR`, then prints that and the next line:

```
#!perl

while( <> ) {
    next unless /ERROR/;
    print;
    print scalar <>;
    }
```

From there you can use `tail` if you like. This Perl does the same as the grep you posted (although since you already have that solution I wonder why you want a different one).

If you don't want to use `tail`, keep track of the two lines you'll output and replace them when you find a new set:

```
my( $error_line, $next_line );
while( <> ) {
    next unless /ERROR/;
    $error_line = $_;
    $next_line = scalar <>;
    }

print $error_line, $next_line;
```

If you have a recent enough perl, you can use the safer [double diamond line input operator](https://www.effectiveperlprogramming.com/2015/05/use-perl-5-22s-operator-for-safe-command-line-handling/):

```
use v5.22;

my( $error_line, $next_line );
while( <<>> ) {
    next unless /ERROR/;
    $error_line = $_;
    $next_line = scalar <<>>;
    }

print $error_line, $next_line;
```

You can use [File::ReadBackwards](https://www.metacpan.org/pod/File::Backwords), but you'll have to do the same task by remembering every line then checking if the previous line had `ERROR`. For you data sizes, the benefit probably isn't apparent. If the simple solution isn't fast enough, it's time to get fancier (but not before then).